# How to calculate correlations across two matrices across samples?

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, bioinformatics

I have methylation count data in the following two matrices.

```
cov <- matrix(sample(0:7, 100,replace=TRUE), nrow=10, ncol=10)
colnames(cov) <- c("group1_1", "group1_2", "group1_3", "group1_4", "group1_5", "group2_1", "group2_2", "group2_3", "group2_4", "group2_5")
meth <- matrix(sample(7:10, 100,replace=TRUE), nrow=10, ncol=10)
colnames(meth) <- c("group1_1", "group1_2", "group1_3", "group1_4", "group1_5", "group2_1", "group2_2", "group2_3", "group2_4", "group2_5")
```

First five samples in each matrix belong to group1, second five samples to group2.

I've been asked to look at correlations across the matrices across samples, with the purpose of identifying outliers. How do I perform this test and what should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
> cor(cov,meth)
            group1_1    group1_2     group1_3    group1_4    group1_5    group2_1    group2_2    group2_3    group2_4    group2_5
group1_1  0.21638563  0.26179603 -0.172564260  0.14098148 -0.11261065 -0.86945839 -0.16405826 -0.32978834  0.26342717 -0.38467159
group1_2 -0.26060328  0.03941164 -0.071940171 -0.21223818 -0.34874292 -0.03197341 -0.10639084 -0.28093179 -0.05287626  0.20590128
group1_3  0.33691014  0.32423812 -0.151250339 -0.06984303  0.06375767 -0.38141390  0.07502345 -0.46224312 -0.08700222 -0.50818268
group1_4 -0.23652496  0.16692770  0.067711562  0.40451992 -0.49236596  0.23699047 -0.33796318 -0.32824398 -0.07465233  0.05450583
group1_5 -0.73285503 -0.50264369  0.527453045  0.40013848 -0.18263739  0.35015790 -0.65736821  0.12892051 -0.55708601  0.08563044
group2_1 -0.08770580  0.33425161  0.150648715  0.12000000 -0.18257419 -0.33895961 -0.07161149 -0.04564355  0.41522740  0.09701425
group2_2 -0.34352146 -0.22627786 -0.163903595  0.24370872  0.19863804 -0.06556144  0.40514370 -0.07945522 -0.72281812  0.04222003
group2_3 -0.08047913 -0.24612562  0.003839882  0.30586777  0.06515082 -0.26495187 -0.23363889 -0.71665901  0.14393864 -0.51928682
group2_4 -0.57395577 -0.58228781  0.344024289  0.35447222  0.54760943  0.13863665  0.20502690 -0.23646771 -0.57742427 -0.23146346
group2_5  0.00000000  0.14099041 -0.020425184 -0.28200960  0.39605902 -0.14297629  0.73789886  0.44556639 -0.40533961  0.28937350
```